# Subquery returned more than 1 value.Not permitted =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE #temp 
SET    duty_count = (SELECT Count(*) 
                     FROM   duty_trak 
                     WHERE  driver_id = #temp.driver_id) 

UPDATE #temp 
SET    vehicle_id = (SELECT vehicle_id 
                     FROM   duty_trak 
                     WHERE  driver_id = #temp.driver_id)
```

In place of equal, I used IN,ALL and Exists but these are not supported. How can remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be more in line with what you are looking for. It uses UPDATE FROM:

```
UPDATE tmp
SET
    tmp.Duty_Count = dutr.Duty_Count
FROM
    #Temp tmp
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        Driver_ID,
        COUNT(*) AS Duty_Count
    FROM
        Duty_Trak
    GROUP BY
        Driver_ID
    ) dutr
    ON (tmp.Driver_ID = dutr.Driver_ID)


UPDATE tmp
SET
    tmp.VEHICLE_ID = dutr.VEHICLE_ID
FROM
    #Temp tmp
JOIN
    Duty_Trak dutr
    ON (tmp.Driver_ID = dutr.Driver_ID)
```

Comment: thanks it works but error occurs invalid driver vehicle combination

Comment: Which statement causes the error and what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to update tmp table with only one value, i guess you can only updated a row with only one value, so, just use "Top 1" with you select statement...